# Output of a function as the input argument of another function in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Let's say I have some predicates and a function like this:

```
fact(a).
fact(b).
fact(c).

main(ListOfFacts) :-
    bagof(Afact, fact(Afact) , ListOfFacts).
```

I would like the `main(R).` (with is `R = [a,b,c]`.) to be passed as an argument of another function, say:

```
mergesort([],[]).
mergesort([A],[A]).
mergesort([A,B|R],S):-
   split([A,B|R],L1,L2),
   mergesort(L1,S1),
   mergesort(L2,S2),
   merge(S1,S2,S).

split([],[],[]).
split([A],[A],[]).
split([A,B|R],[A|Ra],[B|Rb]):-
   split(R,Ra,Rb).

merge(A,[],A).
merge([],B,B).
merge([A|Ra],[B|Rb],[A|M]):-
   A=<B, merge(Ra,[B|Rb],M).
merge([A|Ra],[B|Rb],[B|M]):-
   A>B, merge([A|Ra],Rb,M).
```

We assume there is some way to compare the order of `a`,`b`,`c`.

I tried:

```
mergesort(main(R),A).
```

I expect it returns `A=[sorted a,b,c]`, but it didn't. It trace is simply:

```
 Call: (10) mergesort(main(_8878), _8884) ? creep
   Fail: (10) mergesort(main(_8878), _8884) ? creep
false.
```

Can anyone help on how should I properly pass `main(R)` to the `mergesort`?

Comment: Prolog doesn't have functions. It has predicates. Predicates don't return anything - they just succeed or fail. There is no predicate in your code that can unify with `mergesort(main(R),A)` - hence it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using something like this:

```
main_two(Ans):- main(R), mergesort(R,Ans).
```

feel free to comment on this solution.

Comment: This is how it's done. Prolog has no syntax for nested function applications. (It doesn't even have functions.)

Comment: Yeah. That was what bugged me because initially I had no clue how to pass the output of main as the input of mergesort without giving explicit instruction and without the help of defining some function

Comment: "defining some function" - there are no functions.